# How to specify preceding-sibling inside for-each loop over a variable

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am encountering a syntax error in when I try and use XPath preceding-sibling in an xsl:for-each loop in XSLT 2.0. None of the examples I have seen address this specific case. I am iterating over a sequence of  elemente in the variable $v1. Here is how the XSLT is structured:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$v1/*">
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- minus in previous element means loss -->
      <xsl:when 
          test="matches(preceding-sibling::.[1]/.string(), '-')">     
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:sequence 
              select="concat('Loss: ', ./string()"/>        
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- just copy node and children -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is a simplification of the running code. The working version has other `when` clauses that compile correctly. I'm only showing the `when` clause that give me a compile time error.

The error refers to `Unexpected token "." after axis name`. When I reference the current node I use `matches(./string(), '(\(|\))')` and I have no problem. Why can't I use the same `.` for the previous node?

I'm using Saxon HE9.5.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

> When I reference the current node I use `matches(./string(), '(\(|\))')` and I have no problem. Why can't I use the same `.` for the previous node?

IMHO applying the same notion as `./string()` you mentioned above for `preceding-sibling` would result in the following expression, instead of `preceding-sibling::.[1]/.string()` :

```
./preceding-sibling::*[1]/string()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `matches(preceding-sibling::.[1]/.string(), '-')` you probably simply want `matches(preceding-sibling::*[1], '-')` to match on the immediately preceding sibling element node or `matches(preceding-sibling::node()[1], '-')` to match on any kind of immediately preceding node. There is no need to call `string()`.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works for my case

```
matches(preceding-sibling::td[1]/string(), '-')
```

I'm transforming a sequence of `<td>` elements in my `for-each` loop.